# Kubernetes: how do I specify command to run, for service to start

Tags: kubernetes

I have a docker image that starts the service when I run

```
server start:8080
```

How can I specify this command to be run in Kubernetes Service? 
Is the only option to have it part Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took "Kubernetes" and "specify command to run" from the title of your question and did an Internet search for "Kubernetes specify command to run" and the first result was [this official Kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/). It says:

> When you create a Pod, you can define a command and arguments for the containers that run in the Pod. To define a command, include the `command` field in the configuration file. To define arguments for the command, include the `args` field in the configuration file. The command and arguments that you define cannot be changed after the Pod is created.
>
> The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file override the default command and arguments provided by the container image. If you define args, but do not define a command, the default command is used with your new arguments.
>
> > **Note**: The `command` field corresponds to `entrypoint` in some container runtimes....